# New order emails from Paypal are sending twice

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, email, order-email

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2 and I'm having a problem with New orders emails when the payment is done through Paypal only.

The email is arriving twice to the warehouse and it is complicating things.

In my configuration is set as "CC"

What could be the problem?